# NSF Postdoc Fellowship Announcement?

Tags: funding, nsf

I'm having trouble finding information on when announcements might be made on fellowship awards. I'm specifically interested in Biology "Rules of Life" track.

Comment: First week of February - usually. Now may be different because of covid-19